# Unable to Read Custom Environment Variables in NX App

Tags: reactjs, environment-variables, nrwl-nx

I am unable to read an environment variable called `REACT_APP_API_BASE` from an .env file (`.env.local`) in the root directory of an nx monorepo.

Comment: if you have solved problem by yourself rather than editing question you may add answer.

Answer (score 3):

Pointing to custom env files:

If you want to load variables from env files, use the `env-cmd` package:

```
env-cmd -f .env.local nx serve.
```

I then added the `dotenv` module which loads environment variables from a `.env` file into `process.env`.

I also had to change the name of the environment variable from `REACT_APP_API_BASE` to `NX_API_BASE`.

Now I could read the variable as `process.env.NX_API_BASE` and it returned the value I expected.

Comment: do all variables need to have the `NX_` prepended to them?